# Borsuk-Ulam theorem proof

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is there algebraic topology proof of general Borsuk-Ulam theorem that does not require homology and cohomology theory.

I am learning algebraic topology from Munkres's book Topology and have passed: $\\$

Chapter 9. Fundamental group;
$\\$

Chapter 11. Van Kampen Theorem;
$\\$

Chapter 12. Classification of Covering Spaces.

and now for homework I have to prove Borsuk-Ulam theorem:

If $f:S^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous map than there exists point $x \in S^n$ such that $f(x)=f(-x)$

Comment: I doubt it can be done without homology for $n>2$. When $n=1$, the result follows from mean value theorem and when $n=2$, one can proof the result by contradiction, consider $\displaystyle g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{\|f(x)-f(-x)\|}$ and $\gamma:t\mapsto(\cos(t),\sin(t),0)$ the loop around the ecuador. The loop $g_{\star}\gamma$ is not homotopic to a point.

Comment: I made mistake in copying text ... It should say $\mathbb{R}^n$. I've corrected it now.

Comment: My comment is still relevant, I posted it disregarding the mistake.

Comment: Yes. The trick is to use covering spaces. Specifically $S^n$ is the universal cover of $\mathbb{R}P(n)$.

Comment: @C.Falcon I think you mean *intermediate* value theorem. And I'm interested in your proof of case $n=2$. Why is such a loop not homotopic to a point?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo That's indeed what I meant, thank you for pointing that out! The key point is that $g$ is odd, hence $g_{\star}\gamma(t+\pi)=-g_{\star}\gamma(t)$. Therefore, the lift $\theta$ of $g_{\star}\gamma$ through $t\mapsto(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ such that $\theta(0)=0$ must satisfy $2(\theta(t+\pi)-\theta(t))\in\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, the degree of $g_{\star}\gamma$ is non-zero.

Comment: @C.Falcon Thanks for elucidating : ).